# Is there any reason to check if a property is set before setting it?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm fairly new to VBA. I'm working on an Excel project and I keep seeing code in the project that looks like this:

```
If Me.Columns(i).Hidden = True Then
    Me.Columns(i).Hidden = False
End If
```

and this:

```
If Range("SomeRange").Locked = True Then
    Range("SomeRange").Locked = False
End If
```

*In these cases in particular*, could there be any reason whatsoever for checking if the property is set before setting it, or is this just a useless check? Surely the VBA engine must make an internal check so that it doesn't do anything needlessly.

Comment: The only reason I can think of is that someone was being paid based on the amount of lines of code they wrote. This is not just useless, it's a waste of electricity due to the useless check.

Comment: @Renan, not necessary... See the other possible answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I know the reason someone made the code you analyse. The source of such situation comes possibly from book of **Bovey, Rob/ Wallentin, Dennis/ Bullen, Stephen/ Green, John titled: "Professional Excel Development: The Definitive Guide to Developing Applications Using Microsoft Excel and VBA, and .NET"** which chapters (or complete) you could possible find in the Internet. There is a chapter dedicated to micro- and macro-optimisation. Let's me quote one which refers to your question:

> **Test a Property Before Setting It**
>
> It is often much faster to read a
> property than to write it. It can save time to only update a property
> when it needs to change, by checking whether it has the required value
> first. For example, reading the value of Range.Font.Bold and only
> setting it to True if it isn’t True already. This contradicts the
> general rule of reducing the amount of code you write, but it will
> provide a significant performance increase if it allows you to avoid
> setting properties unnecessarily.

I will not confirm whether its true or not. But I rather trust authors of the book.

Comment: KazJaw, thanks for the reference and for the quote. For some properties the `significant performance increase` is straightforward: in a large pivot table, for instance, setting properties like `ViewCalculatedMembers` without checking will probably make a difference.. But what about stuff like `Range("SomeRange").Locked = True ` ? Is it not too extreme to clutter the notation with this kind of checking, in your opinion?

Comment: @Ioannis, Look in the quoted text- there is simple `Range.Font.Bold` example which is really doubtful. I've never tested it (which wouldn't be difficult) but I rather trust authors to some extend. In the complete paragraph referring to code optimisation process there are some other interesting tips which make the whole text convincing.

Comment: running a quick test on a complete column in 2010 with all cells unlocked, using `If Range("A" & n).Locked Then Range("A" & n).Locked = False` is over 40 seconds faster on average than simply using `Range("A" & n).Locked = False`. in real life there will be considerable variations based on circumstances! ;-)

Comment: I will say that in Microsoft Access I have actually had application crashes when setting properties too often in a complex user interface. Changing the code to check the property first before just setting it (and avoiding unneeded sets) resolved the crashes and improved overall performance. I don't do it all the time, but it can make a difference in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a useless check. I don't see much reason why you would have an extra check unless there is some other logic involved when a particular column/row is hidden.